# No write permissions with Access db in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2007, ado

I am using the following connectionstring:

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=hrdadmin;User ID=Admin;" & _
"DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("db/database.mdb")
```

Within a simple w3schools ADO update script (http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_update.asp) hosted on jabry.net

```vb
<html>
<body>

<h2>Update Record</h2>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"

cid=Request.Form("customerID")

if Request.form("companyname")="" then
  set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  rs.open "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID='" & cid & "'",conn
  %>
  <form method="post" action="demo_update.asp">
  <table>
  <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
  <tr>
  <td><%=x.name%></td>
  <td><input name="<%=x.name%>" value="<%=x.value%>"></td>
  <%next%>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Update record">
  </form>
<%
else
  sql="UPDATE customers SET "
  sql=sql & "companyname='" & Request.Form("companyname") & "',"
  sql=sql & "contactname='" & Request.Form("contactname") & "',"
  sql=sql & "address='" & Request.Form("address") & "',"
  sql=sql & "city='" & Request.Form("city") & "',"
  sql=sql & "postalcode='" & Request.Form("postalcode") & "',"
  sql=sql & "country='" & Request.Form("country") & "'"
  sql=sql & " WHERE customerID='" & cid & "'"
  on error resume next
  conn.Execute sql
  if err<>0 then
    response.write("No update permissions!")
  else
    response.write("Record " & cid & " was updated!")
  end if
end if
conn.close
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine until I try the update function, it says "No writing permissions".

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas?, hmm... *"No writing permissions"* what do you think? This is just a stab in the dark but maybe your IIS `ApplicationPoolIdentity` user doesn't have access to write privileges to the access database. I'd start by checking the NTFS permissions for that folder.

Comment: @Lankymart I am using webhost jabry.net who states "You must place your database in your "db" directory. This directory has write permissions." and the database is in that db directory.

Comment: In which case the configuration is hidden from you, so you would be best asking the webhost (directly or via their support forum if they have one) why it's not allowing write access to the database.

Comment: I should probably clarify this is not ASP giving me the no writing permissions error, the script prints it when the update fails.

Comment: @Lankymart okay I'll give that a go, but other than that, would you say my connection string looks correct?

Comment: Ok, so the error could be anything to do with the connection, sorry should have checked the script first. Try commenting out `On Error Resume Next` and see what actual error is being raised.

Comment: @Lankymart that's alright man I should have posted the script too. thanks for your help, i figured it out. commenting out that line showed me there was a syntax error in my query. all smooth now.

Comment: When asking questions on SO it's generally best to include your code (regardless if it is a sample from somewhere else) that way you will get better help. Also I wouldn't recommend w3schools as I very good reference when it comes to code samples. For instance that entire script is open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), consider using `ADODB.Command` object instead to build parametrised queries.

Comment: As @Lankymart says, you are open to sql injection, but not only that, you have made no attempt to escape single quotes in your input, so you can avoid two major problems with parameters.